# Insert 2 image on the figure when I have corresponding x and y coordinates

Tags: matlab

I need any guidance about how I can insert two .png images on the current figure (that is a map of the country) by having x and y coordinates of each png. I did this in PowerPoint (see the figure below) but as I have more than 2000 points it would be awesome if it is possible to do it by Matlab.

[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huDB9.jpg)

The current figure is the country map and my two png's are these two colorful circles.

Thank you all

Comment: [**`image`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy approach: Say `im1` is your circles map and `im2` is the Iran's map.

```
im1 = ones(64);
im1(20:40,20:40) = 0.5; 
im2 = rand(64);

figure
imshow(im1,[]);
hold on
h = imshow(im2,[]);
h.AlphaData = 0.3; % or whatever Transparency makes you happy
```